# How to support all cultures on machine in applications using different .NET versions?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have 2 applications, Application1 uses .NET 4 and Application2 uses .NET 6, I'm trying get all machine supported cultures using `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`, but there is a difference in the cultures fetched in both applications run on the same machine, in Application1 using .NET 4 I see more cultures and in Application2 using .NET 6 I see less cultures. But I need all cultures supported in Application1 to be supported in Application2. Is there a way to achieve this?

And I'm using this logic in Application2 to add supported cultures to `RequestLocalizationOptions options.AddSupportedCultures()` in `Program.cs`, is there any way all supported cultures can be taken implicitly without using this fetch cultures logic?

I tried adding languages required in `appsettings.json` but I don't want to go with that solution as every time a language needs to be added I need to modify the supported list, I want to find a way to read all supported cultures on the machine, and I want to know if there is any way all supported cultures can be taken implicitly without using this fetch cultures logic?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you expect the list of cultures to never change? What do you mean by "supported on the machine"? The culture list behaves differently in .Net 6 compared to .net framework as documented in `CultureTypes.AllCultures`, this is probably something you need to deal with.

Comment: There are two sources for cultures. Windows own mechanism and the one provided by ICU to be plattform independent (in the Net Core world). Both sources can(and will) differ on different system. I already have a problem understanding what you expect with saying "All Cultures". All Cultures of what?  There is no global definition for that. If you need that for transport between systems then don't do that. You can't expect  that a specific culture will exists on a different system.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give an example of a culture that exists in one but not in the other?

Comment: @JonasH I am aware the culture list behaves differently in .net6 and .net framework, I was curious if there is a way we can access .net framework's the list of cultures from CultureTypes.AllCultures in .net 6 application, thanks for the response

Comment: @Ralf In my context by All cultures I meant the list of cultures I get from CultureTypes.AllCultures, I want to support all the cultures returned by CultureTypes.AllCultures in .net framework in .net 6 application when run on the same system

Comment: @Magnus  The list of cultures returned on .Net 4 had "zh-TW" but it was missing in the list of cultures when run on .Net 6 in my local machine, this is one example I found

Comment: You might try setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization#nls in the proper spot for your Net 6 Application. Net 6 should then return the same thing as the classic Net Framework. Afaik there is no (simple) way to get the ICU stuff in Net 4.